# i can't personally todos react native firestore

Tags: firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I made a todo app using firebase. I store the todos in firestore and save the email address of the user who added the todo into the document. but when a user saves todo, all users see that todo. my codes:

```
const [dailys, setDailys] = useState([]);
const dailyRef = firebase.firestore().collection('daily');
const [addDaily, setAddDaily] = useState('');
const email = firebase.auth().currentUser.email;

useEffect(() => {
    async function check() {
        dailyRef.orderBy('createdAt', 'desc')
            .onSnapshot(
                querySnapShot => {
                    const dailys = []
                    querySnapShot.forEach((doc) => {
                        const { heading } = doc.data()
                        dailys.push({
                            id: doc.id,
                            heading,
                            email: email,
                        })
                    })
                    setDailys(dailys)
                }
            )
    }
    check()
}, [])
const addDailyPlan = () => {
    if (addDaily && addDaily.length > 0) {
        const timeStamp = firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp();
        const daily = {
            email:email,
            heading: addDaily,
            createdAt: timeStamp
        };
        dailyRef
            .add(daily)
            .then(() => {
                setAddDaily('');
                Keyboard.dismiss();
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                alert(error);
            })
    }
}
render(
 <FlatList data={dailys}/>
```

)

Answer (score 0):

If everyone is pushing in the same collection, everyone will have the same result...

Either create a specific collection for each user (recommended), or add this to your query => where("email", "==", email)

Read [the docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#simple_queries) for reference